# Why docker build flag --add-host is not working on linux ubuntu ?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am trying to run my docker development setup and I can't access host
from

```
docker build --add-host mymachinelocalip:ss-local
```

in my production ubuntu envrionment, by caling in **Dockerfile**:

```
RUN curl -f http://ss-local:8181
```

my **/etc/hosts** :

```
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.1  ss-local
172.17.0.5  e1ede117fb1e
```

On my local computer (MacOSX El Capitan and Windows10) everything works perfect..
But on digitalocean droplet with Ubuntu curl command fail.

I am beginer with docker.. and I am wondering maybe there is some
kind of firewall on linux that prevent connections to host...

**Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS** with **Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87**.

Comment: Do you get the same issue if the --add-host mapping is done at run time and using an IP address different then the docker0 interface. i(ie: docker run -ti --add-host "ss-local:192.168.120.154" ubuntu bash)

Comment: it is not working also at runtime...

Comment: Temporary solution: downgrade to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS....

Answer (score 4):

When you pass --add-host to docker *build*, the host is only added during the build. If you pass --add-host to docker *run*, the host will be present at runtime.

Reference: https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/30383#issuecomment-314797629